# Using Winforms to connect to SQL Server to easily filter data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Winforms that is connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database.

I would like to be able to easily filter through data in one table.

Here is an example of what I would like:

- there are 3 columns in the table, and I will have three textboxes (or any other useful control) on a form that will correspond to those three columns.
- the user will be able to input a value in any one of those fields and retrieve the rest of the values pertaining to that field.

Is there already an easy solution for this?

Comment: If the table you want to filter is quite small and do not change often (or even is read-only), consider another approach: query database only once to download all data to DataTable, that you display i.e. in DataGridView, then use datatable's `.DefaultView.RowFilter  = ...` to apply filter to DataTable object. Thanks to that you don't have to connect and query database each time you change filter critery.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use DataSet or DataReader.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a yet unique way of doing this. Anyways, you can simply use a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y1499) it will allow you to execute a storedprocedure or a query as you like. The you pass the three filter values as [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Here is a little example:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable Where (FieldOne == @ParameterOne Or FieldTwo = @ParameterTwo Or FieldThree = @ParameterThree)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        // Create the command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        // Add the parameters

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ParameterOne", txtMyTextBox1.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ParameterTwo", txtMyTextBox2.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ParameterThree", txtMyTextBox3.Text));
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use the SqlDataReader to get the values.